# NFS v4 - `nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -512` after reboot

Tags: centos, nfs

Just began with NFS v4. I got these settings in `/etc/fstab`:

```
1.2.3.4:/mnt/exports/content-nl /data2/objects    nfs4 minorversion=1,ro,defaults,_netdev 0 0
2.2.2.4:/mnt/exports/www-nl     /data/nl          nfs4 minorversion=1,ro,defaults,_netdev 0 0
3.2.3.4:/mnt/exports/content-be /data2/be_objects nfs4 minorversion=1,ro,defaults,_netdev 0 0
4.2.3.4:/mnt/exports/www-be     /data/be          nfs4 minorversion=1,ro,defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

Ip's are fake ofc...

After a reboot on the client, I see these messages in /var/log/messages

```
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: data2-be_objects.mount mounting timed out. Stopping.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: data-be.mount mounting timed out. Stopping.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: Mounted /data2/be_objects.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: Mounted /data/be.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: data-nl.mount mounting timed out. Stopping.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 kernel: NFS: nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -512. Exiting with error EIO
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: Mounted /data/nl.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: data2-objects.mount mounting timed out. Stopping.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 kernel: NFS: nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -512. Exiting with error EIO
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 kernel: NFS: nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -512. Exiting with error EIO
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 kernel: NFS: nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -512. Exiting with error EIO
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: Mounted /data2/objects.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: Reached target Remote File Systems.
Apr 19 12:25:51 node1 systemd: Starting Remote File Systems.
```

The mount is actually mounted and I can perform writes on the mount.

What does the kernel message mean? Should I change something in my config or can these messages be ignored?

Been googling around, but nothing relevant came up.

Using CentOS 7.3

Comment: 1.2.3.4 <<< where did you get this IP from? Is this really the IP of the mount point? The IP should be that of the server providing the nfs share.

You appear to have entered random IP's instead of the servers IP (presuming they all come from the same server).

Comment: Fake ip's ofc..

Comment: Why? No one cares what IP your NFS share is on, and I'm hoping it's not shared on a public IP anyway.
You've confused the issue by hiding valuable information.

Comment: Also the issue appears to be that your server isn't running nfs4, that'd be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: It is.. By performing nfsstat -s -l, the statistics are only of nfs v4

Comment: What about NFS server or servers, judging from IPs I'm not sure if its one or four? Post OS, kernel version, `/etc/exports`? This seems more of a server related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Things I'd try:

- Passing the `sec=sys` option
- Disabling any GSS/Kerberos NFS options you can see in your distro if you're not using them

If neither of those work (they didn't for me), you could try just blacklisting the `rpcsec_gss_krb5` via modprobe.d:

```
echo 'blacklist rpcsec_gss_krb5' > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rpcsec-gss-krb5.conf
reboot
```

Obviously, you'd only do that if you're not using any Kerberos features, and just want your automounting NFS back :)

The other caveat is that this is probably a bug, and should just work. There is, for example, [this recent Redhat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1428941) for "nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -512" which has been marked as a duplicate of a non-public bug.